How to use php bref newrelic extension for AWS Lambda?
I am deploying one laravel application via bref into AWS lambda.
It works great.
I want to add newrelic to my lambda as well.
I am following the documentation here
https://github.com/brefphp/extra-php-extensions/blob/master/docs/newrelic.md
I did create in my repository php/conf.d/newrelic-settings.ini file as documented with the content
newrelic.appname = "test-development"
newrelic.license = "reallicencehere"


I also added the newrelic lambda layer into the serverless.yaml file
        layers:
            - ${bref-extra:redis-php-82}
            - ${bref-extra:gd-php-82}
            - ${bref-extra:newrelic-php-82}

I deployed my lambda but I still do not get anything on newrelic.

How can I fix this so newrelic is getting data ?
I would also like to know how to troubleshoot this. I see that this newrelic layer is an aws lambda layer and I can't find a way to "ssh" or see what happens inside it


You may test it locally first with docker-compose - https://github.com/brefphp/extra-php-extensions?tab=readme-ov-file#local-development to see if your newrelic settings works or not. After that, try adding more settings such as logging to CloudWatch logs, i suggest. SSH remote to Lambda layers or other troubleshooting is not capable i believe.

How can I debug it locally with docker-compose though ? I use serverless deploy --stage=dev and do deploy the lambda fine into AWS
